# Eclim - don't switch focus to output

Tags: vim, switch, buffer, focus

Just starting with Eclim, one of the gripes I still have is the fact that the my cursor is switched away from the file I'm editing when I call `:Java`. On top of that, it opens a new buffer asking me to `Press ENTER or type command to continue`. After pressing enter the output is still visible on a small buffer on the bottom, which is what I like. At this point my cursor is in the output buffer.

So, is it possible to disable the `Press ENTER...` buffer from opening up and then disable the output buffer from grabbing focus?

Comment: I use system("xdotool") in my vim functions to save the current window, and restore focus to it for actions that change focus.  The rest of what you want would require the :Java command to execute external utilities with :silent.  Not posting this as an answer, because altering the plug-in source is probably not the best, and I don't know if you're using xorg.

Comment: I'm actually on wayland, so xdotool is a no-go. I don't think there is (yet) a replacement that works on wayland

Comment: Cool, well good luck. Hopefully someone who uses the plug-in will be able to help you.

Comment: I actually solved the first part, the `Press ENTER` dialogue by appending <CR> to my keybinding. However, I would still like to solve the focus issue